# D3 filled gauge - is it possible to dynamically update the color of the filing circle through d3 itself?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to dynamically update the color of the filing circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only possible, but fun for all the family..

I have a function to set the colors eg:

```
function getColor(num){
    if( num >= 9 ){
            return '#E72530';
    } else if( num >= 7 ){
            return '#EAAB0E';
    } else if( num >= 5){
            return '#FFE400';
    } else if( num >= 3 ){
            return '#187AD3';
    } else {
            return '#00ADGE';
    }
}
```

So, from there I have my gauge(s) which call the getColor function with a number from the returned data from getData. The getData url calls an API which returns json data. Based on this level, will change the color

```
function loadStuff(){
    $.getJSON('/getData', function(d) {
            var ccolor = getColor(d.level);
            var config1 = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();
            config1.circleColor = ccolor;
            config1.textColor = "#ffffff";
            config1.waveTextColor = "#ffffff";
            config1.waveColor = ccolor;
            config1.circleThickness = 0.2;
            config1.textVertPosition = 0.2;
            config1.waveAnimateTime = 1000;
            config1.displayPercent = false;
            var gauge1 = loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge1", d.level*10, config1);
    });
```

By now you have noticed this will only work when the page is loaded. I can you thinking "what a shame", but help is at hand.

You can call the loadStuff function when the page is loaded, and then set a timer to do it at whatever interval you like.

```
window.onload = function () {
    //Make sure the function fire as soon as the page is loaded
    loadStuff();

    // run the function every 60 seconds
    setInterval(function() {
            loadStuff();
    }, 60 * 1000); // 60 * 1000 milsec
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, great idea! I ended up not using because I already had a timer to play changing the interval based on my data structures, and it was too much flickering..